# Crash with Async Task

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

Apologies for my question but I am very noob in android studio.

I have an app which is a simple web view app with push notifications every time new content is added in a web site. I'm trying to register with google cloud messages and I've been trying to send a push notification message to three devices but always get the same result:

```
{"multicast_id":5069213226545235739,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}{"registration_ids":["APA91bEl0UpCC7r0BcpYpI-4l_XGSXrUR1cMMQM2it2rIhICX61FQSIBXAN2_fE2INxG8PE2F8gcPtJgHX-Gm78YhPuDO6j1UFU0lUpK....etc"],"data":{"message":"New content available!"}}
```

I've tried changing the server key to the browser key, etc... 
I've finally managed to erase the shared preferences, recompile my app and then I realized my app was crashing when registering in background with an Async Task. I've never notified before because the reg_id were stored in the shared prefs. I've copied the async task from google examples, 
I am stuck however with android studio and his syntax and some help would be very handy to find were the error is.
This is my crash log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.alfredo.webapp.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:215)
        at com.example.alfredo.webapp.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:197)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Here is my code:

```
private void registerInBackground() {

        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);


                    msg = "Device registered, registration id=" + regid;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                    // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.

                    // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                    // will send upstream messages to a server that will echo back
                    // the message using the 'from' address in the message.

                    // Save the regid for future use - no need to register again.
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regid);
                    editor.commit();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;
            }
            // Once registration is done, display the registration status
            // string in the Activity's UI.
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

Comment: Its Clearly a null pointer exception at line #215 of your MainActivity

Comment: Can you tell us what is in the line doInBackground(MainActivity.java:215) and doInBackground(MainActivity.java:197) ?

Comment: I think `gcm=null`. Create it `gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);`

Comment: I think you forgot to intialize gcm object.

Comment: `prefs` value is `null` per your stacktrace, probably you forgot to initialize it

Comment: @nikis  :) You counted the lines :) I did it too....I think You´re wright...

Comment: @nikis I also think you are right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check what is on line 215 in your MainActivity.java

Wild guess: either its 'gcm' or 'prefs'.

Please check if they are initialized before calling .execute();

Answer (score 0):

initialize `gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);`

Answer (score 0):

What is the line #215 of your code ?
From your code it looks like any one of the `gcm`, `prefs` or `mDisplay` can be null to show this error..